# Quadratic programming to SDP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, semidefinite-programming

Assume I have an quadratic program of the form:
\begin{align*}
\min&&&\|LA-B\|^2\\
\text{s.t.}&&& \text{Tr}A=1\\
&&&A \succeq 0
\end{align*}
Here $A,B,C,L$ are all $n\times n$ real matrices, while the last term implies the constraint that $A$ is positive semi-definite. The **question** is how to bring this to the standard SDP form
\begin{align*}
\min&&&\langle C,X\rangle \\
\text{s.t.}&&&\langle Q_i, X \rangle = b_i \\
&&&X \succeq 0
\end{align*}
where $\langle C, X \rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(CX)$. I understand that there is the complement trick by Schur but I struggle to apply it. Not sure how to do it.

**More generally, how to bring a quadratic program (one whose objective is a quadratic function) to the standard conic SDP form?**

Comment: The important question is what your final goal is, as you wouldn't want to write the model in a simple SDP form in practice, but exploit the quadratic form and write as a mixed SDP/SOCP model, as most available solvers would exploit that.

Comment: Even in that case, I would like to see how this is possible. Any references or tips?

Comment: The constraint $t\geq x^2$ is equivalent to $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&x\\ x&t\end{array}\right]\succeq0.$ From there you can reformulate the sum of squares in the objective. Like Johan mentioned, this is only of theoretical interest perhaps, showing that an SOCP is a special case of an SDP.

Comment: I am very confused as to what small $x$ is. Is the matrix quoted above supposed to represent $X$? At the moment I am indeed interested in the theory. But its not clear how to show this is SDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work in a pure primal standard mixed SDP/SOCP cone you would have to introduce a new object $e = (e_0,e) \in R\times R^{n\times n}$ to represent the SOCP cone and replace the objective with $e_0$ and connect the two cones with the primal equalities $e = \text{vec}(LA-B)$ (which I will not write using inner products as that is absurdly low level).

\begin{align*}
\min&&& e_0 \\
\text{s.t.}&&&\text{Tr} A =1  \\
&&&e = \text{vec}(LA-B)\\
&&&A \succeq_{SDP} 0, (e_0,e) \succeq_{SOCP} 0
\end{align*}

It is not certain you want to stay in a pure primal form (as you will be forced to introduce a large number of primal equalities), but instead interpret $A$ as a matrix defined by its elements as decision variables, and then skip also the definition of a cone variable for the SOCP and interpret everything from the dual side. The size of this model would be $n(n+1)/2$ (the number of variables defining elements of symmetric matrix $A$) while the size of the primal model would be $n^2+1$ (the number of equalities)

\begin{align*}
\min&&& e_0 \\
\text{s.t.}&&& \text{Tr} A =1 \\
&&&A \succeq_{SDP} 0, \\
&&&(e_0,\text{vec}(LA-B)) \succeq_{SOCP} 0
\end{align*}

You typically do not do all this in practice (and we haven't even started with the really low-level boring stuff with inner products to define the equalities explicitly) but use modelling languages for this. The code would look something like this (here in YALMIP)

```
A = sdpvar(n)
optimize([A>=0, trace(A)==1],norm(L*A-B))
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what the $e_0$ object is. Is this the variable appearing due to the Schur trick? P.S. my background is in differential topology so I am not familiar with the field and I am confused as to what you mean by "low level boring...".

Comment: Since $(e_0,e)$ in SOCP cone mean $||e||\leq e_0$ and $e$ is constrained to be equal to the elements in $LA−B$, $e_0$ will serve as an upper bound to $||LA−B||$. Low-level mean writing all the equalities in, e.g., $e=\text{vec}(LA−B)$ in the format $\langle Q^1_{i},A \rangle +\langle Q^2_{i},(e_0,e) \rangle = b_i$

Comment: I am still having a hard time understand this program. In the constraints it is completely unclear that $e_0$ is somehow related to $e$. I do understand the $A \succeq _{SDP} 0$ equation but not the $(e_0,e)\succeq_{SOCP} 0$ one. Would you mind expanding?

Comment: it's just a notation for the socp-cone $||e|| \leq  e_0$

Comment: Thanks. But, how do you prove that the two formulations are equivalent?

Comment: Which? The ones I have listed are equivalent by construction, the only thing happening is that there is an additional variable to write it in a (for practical reasons unnecessary) slightly more canonical form. It's like asking how to prove that minimizing $(x+1)^2$ is equivalent to minimize $e^2$ under the constraint $e=x+1$. Sure you can write a formal proof but why...It also raises the question what equivalent means.

Comment: A solver should return equal minima, right? I have not tried it yet, but will do.

Comment: If solution is unique, yes.

Comment: @JohanLofbeg thanks a lot. Unfortunately with CVXPY I do get slightly different results. Furthermore, referring to a previous comment, I dont quite see how taking the norm of $LA-B$ as a constraint somehow substitutes the original quadratic part. Please excuse my ignorance, my background is in differential topology and physics, not in optimization.

Comment: Minimizing $||x||^2$ is the same thing as minimizing $||x||$ which is the same thing as minimizing $t$ with the constraints $||x||\leq t$.

Comment: I managed to make it work (almost). The optimal value I get for least squares is 1.2554595390720102 while for the reformulation is 1.1204729098592683. Nevertheless, the matrix $a \equiv {\rm vec}(A)$ is very close: [0.58886134 0.57401336 0.41006725 0.41113865] vs [0.58887007 0.57401659 0.41006087 0.41112993]. Some idea of where the discrepancy be due to?

Comment: I guess you are missing the fact that the new objective will be the square-root of the objective of the original model...